# Stochastic Differential Equation for a reflected Brownian motion

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion

Is there a SDE for a (one-dimensional) reflected (at 0) drifted Brownian motion  like
$d X_t = \mu dt + \sigma d W_t$ for the normal Brownian motion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As discussed in [this blog post](https://eventuallyalmosteverywhere.wordpress.com/2014/04/21/reflected-brownian-motion/), reflected Brownian motion satisfies the SDE
$$
dX_t=\textrm{sign}(B_t)\ dB_t,
$$
where $X_t=|B_t|$ is the reflected Brownian motion, and
$$
\textrm{sign}(x)=\begin{cases}1,&x>0\\0,&x=0\\-1,&x<0.\end{cases}
$$

Comment: What is the second derivative of absolute function?

Comment: I know why you are asking this, but it is not directly part of this question. Per the site guidelines, you should ask it in another question.

Comment: This is not correct. There is no reason for $X_t=\int_0^t \mathop{sign}(B_s)dB_s$ to be a.s. positive., since is centred Gaussian with mean t. Actually, by Lévy characterization of Brownian motion, $(X_t)_{t\geq0}$ is again a Brownian motion.

Comment: @pre-kidney Perhaps he was asking because the second derivative is pretty relevant for It\^o's formula...